# Simple Visual basic q in an excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim test As String

test = CStr(ActiveWorkSheet.VLookup("jpeg_lrg", B, 3))
```

stupid 424 error help!

for my macro in excel vba

---

```
Dim test As String

test = CStr(ActiveWorkSheet.VLookup("jpeg_lrg", B44, 3))
```

(didnt work as well)

---

also tried without the CSTR

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're trying to achieve, otherwise we can't help you

Comment: Does the code compile? Use Debug menu -> Compile to check. At 1st, `VLOOKUP` isnt a function on the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just pass you ranges as variable names.

```
Dim test As String

test = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("jpeg_lrg", ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"), 3)
```

That won't make any sense though, because "B:B" only contains one column, and you ask it for column three. With VLookup you want at least two columns in the range.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to return the value of the cell of E44?
If that is the case, then this should work for you - replace `MsgBox` with the code you require.

```
For Each i In Range("B44")
    If i = "jpeg_lrg" Then
        MsgBox i.Offset(0, 2)
        Else
    End If
Next i
```